# Refresh activity when internet is coming

Tags: android, android-activity

I make some code to refresh **MainActivity** activity when internet is coming but I have problem when I put some method in activity to make refresh activity it's always return null to me. 
I call activity method **upadetStateConnection** from **InternetReceiver** class, when internet is coming.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
public void upadetStateConnection() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();///null 
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Class for check connection is come or not:

```
public class InternetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void notificationStateInternet() {
        MainActivity kl= new MainActivity();
        kl.upadetStateConnection();
    }

    //check state internet
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfoWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfoMobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        boolean isConnected = (activeNetInfoWifi != null && activeNetInfoWifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (activeNetInfoMobile != null && activeNetInfoMobile.isConnectedOrConnecting());
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("MyData", true);
        if (isConnected) {
            notificationStateInternet();
            Log.i("NET", "connecte" + isConnected);
        } else {

            Log.i("NET", "not connecte" + isConnected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is that reaching onRecieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
MainActivity kl= new MainActivity();
kl.upadetStateConnection();
```

theses lines causing issue because trying to access method by create object of class which is extending Activity and that why `getIntent()` method call always returning `null` or `NullPointerException` because Context is invalid.

> code to refresh MainActivity activity when internet is coming

Make `InternetReceiver` class as inner class of `MainActivity` then call `upadetStateConnection` method from inner class without creating object like:

```
   public void notificationStateInternet() { 
        upadetStateConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so mush for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Start your activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: show me that error: com.android.tofi.mohammad.popularmovies.MainActivity.upadetStateConnection(MainActivity.java:35)
            at     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.android.tofi.mohammad.popularmovies.InternetReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat com.android.tofi.mohammad.popularmovies.MainActivity.upadetStateConnection(MainActivity.java:35)
com.android.popularmovies.InternetReceiver.notificationStateInternet(InternetReceiver.java:18)
            at com.android.tofi.mohammad.popularmovies.InternetReceiver.onReceive(InternetReceiver.java:35)